# Show number of selected cells

Tags: javascript

I have the following code to turn cells clicked on to green but I'm trying to have on top of the web page a paragraph with '*number of selected green cells:*' with the number of selected green cells. I can't figure it out. I'd also need to record in a file on the website (../coordinates.txt) the x,y coordonate of all selected green cells after clicking on the "confirm" button.
Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

CSS

```
.green { background: green; color: white; }
.white { background: white; color: black; }

#cells-list { border: 1px solid black; }
td { padding: 10px; border: 1px solid black; }
```

HTML

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 3</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Untitled_1.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" Text="Confirm" />
</form>

<table id="cells-list">
<tr>
<td class="white">TEST1</td>
<td class="white">TEST2</td>
<td class="white">TEST3</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
var cells = document.querySelectorAll("td");
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
cells[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
this.className= this.className == "white" ? "green" : "white";
});
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```js
var numberOfSelectedCellsElem = document.querySelector('#numberOfSelectedCells');
document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(c => {
  c.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.className = this.className == 'white' ? 'green' : 'white';
    numberOfSelectedCellsElem.innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('.green').length;
  });
});
```

```css
.green {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.white {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

#cells-list {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>number of selected green cells: <span id="numberOfSelectedCells">0</span></p>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" Text="Confirm" />
</form>

<table id="cells-list">
  <tr>
    <td class="white">TEST1</td>
    <td class="white">TEST2</td>
    <td class="white">TEST3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much Yosvel :-) I appriciate your help :-)